# HTML Special characters in preprocess

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to add a bullet to a string in `_preprocess_node()` and am running into problems.
I am using Drupal 7.

My code is as such:

```
if($node->type == 'contact_page'){
    $vars['content']['field_fax']['#title'] = t("F &#8226;");
    $vars['content']['field_phone']['#title'] = t("P &#8226;");
  }
```

I get the literal string instead of the bullet. I've tried a bunch of things, but nothing seems to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
t("F !bullet", array("!bullet" => "&#8226;"));
t("P !bullet", array("!bullet" => "&#8226;"));
```

Drupal escapes any characters passed through t() function so you need to use variables like this:

- @variable: Escaped to HTML using check_plain(). Use this as the
  default choice for anything displayed on a page on the site.
- %variable: Escaped to HTML and formatted using drupal_placeholder(),
  which makes it display as *emphasized* text.
- !variable: Inserted as is, with no sanitization or formatting. Only
  use this for text that has already been prepared for HTML display
  (for example, user-supplied text that has already been run through
  check_plain() previously, or is expected to contain some limited HTML
  tags and has already been run through filter_xss() previously).

Comment: i tried this and it didn't *quite* work.When I did:  t("F !bullet", array("!bullet" => "•")); it worked, but I feel like using the special character in my code is bad practice.

Comment: maybe you can use &bull; ?

Comment: tried that too!
We changed the design rather than spend too much time on it.

If I don't get the "right" answer eventually, I'm going to just accept this one as its "close enough."

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and after hours of searching I finally found something that works. Try decode_entities

```
if($node->type == 'contact_page'){
    $vars['content']['field_fax']['#title'] = decode_entities("F &#8226;");
    $vars['content']['field_phone']['#title'] = decode_entities("P &#8226;");   
}
```

Comment: The reason for this problem is that the label is being passed through check_plain(), which translates characters to their HTML equivalents. So you cannot put HTML into it directly, and that's also why using the special character works OK. The decode_entities() approach is fine for avoiding having the special character as a literal in source, though it does mean it gets decoded and recoded again, which seems a bit redundant.